# How to return an array to separate class?

Tags: java, arrays, return

If I write out an array the long way in a seperate class such as

```
public Student [] getArray(){
    Student [] studentArray = new Student[3];
    studentArray[0] = new Student (”Mel”);
    studentArray[1] = new Student (”Jared”);
    studentArray[2] = new Student (”Mikey”);
    return studentArray;
}
```

Will the return statement return all the names to my other class that I'm actually going to run, or just one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the `return` statement will return the entire array, which means that the caller can access all three of the `Student` objects.  For example:

```
Student[] arr = getArray();
System.out.println(arr[0]); // Prints out Mel student
System.out.println(arr[1]); // Prints out Jared student
System.out.println(arr[2]); // Prints out Mikey student
```

If you want to return just one `Student`, then your return type would be `Student` and you would have to specifically pick which one to return.  In Java, returning an array always returns the entire array, and you don't need to say that you're returning all of the contents with it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Of course all the names. It returns your **array** which contains all your created Students.
I guess youre new to programming. So read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) to know what are arrays and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
Student[] studentArray = new Student[3];
```

creates a *new array*, capable of holding *three references to Student instances* and assigns the *reference* to this array to the *local variable* `studentArray`

```
return studentArray;
```

returns the reference to this array to the caller of the method. He can use this array reference to get the references of the `Student` objects.

He can either store it in another variable or use it directly:

```
Student[] callersArray = getArray();
System.out.println(callersArray[0]);  // will print a Student "Mel"

System.out.println(getArray()[0]);    // will print another(!) Student "Mel"
```

Answer (score 0):

All values of the array are returned.
You can write it shorter:

```
public Student [] getArray(){
  return new Student[]{new Student (”Mel”), new Student (”Jared”), new Student (”Jared”)};
}
```